# Getting arraylist from jsp page's hidden field to action class using struts2

Tags: java, list, jsp, struts2, hidden-field

I have an arraylist which i have set into jsp's hiddenField.Now I have to access this list in my action class. Below,code snippets are as follows

My action Class

```
private ArrayList<TXT_File_Action> statusResult_list=new ArrayList<TXT_File_Action>();
    private ArrayList<TXT_Beans> regenerateTXTList=new ArrayList<TXT_Beans>();
    private ArrayList<TXT_Beans> pagingList=new ArrayList<TXT_Beans>();
    private ArrayList<TXT_Beans> serverList=new ArrayList<TXT_Beans>();



public String getGenerateList()
    {

          for(int j=0;j<customers_accountList.size();j++)
               {

               dataList=txt_managerInstance.regenerateListData(id_no);  
               regenerateTXTList.add(dataList.get(0));
           }

               pagingList=getRegenerateTXTList();
               setRegenerateTXTList(getRegenerateTXTList());
               setPagingList(getPagingList());

        return SUCCESS;
      }

  getters..n setters
```

My JSP code is

```
 <s:iterator value="pagingList">
<tr>
     <td align="center"><s:property value="customerId" /></td>  
     <td align="center"><s:property value="cspId" /></td>    
     <td align="center"><s:property value="branchCode" /></td>
     <td align="center" id="bcID"><s:property value="bcCode"/></td>
 </tr>

</s:iterator>
```

and below I set the list in jsp hidden field like this :

```
   <input type="hidden" name="serverList" id="serverList"  value="<s:property value="pagingList"/>"/>
```

Now I want this list in my action class when I click to an event.
Whenever I tried to print the size of this list **serverList** in my action I got following error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    com.alw.action.TXT_File_Action.setPaginationList(TXT_File_Action.java:424)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        .
        .
        .
```

But I sure i get all Arrayllist data in this hidden field because I have checked this on my page

```
**<input type="hidden" name="serverList" id="serverList"  value="<s:property value="pagingList"/>"/>**
```

what is going wrong with this, How to get this list in my action class.
any help would be very helpfull.

Comment: What on earth is setPagingList(getPagingList()); :O

Comment: its nothing but juss my coding style, is it a bad practice?

Comment: No, but it does nothing... you set a variable with the current value of that variable (unless, of course, you have business logic into getters and setters. and THAT would be a bad practice).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot put a `List` or any `Object` directly into a `input` or `s:hidden`, here is the [DOCUMENT](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.3/docs/hidden.html), attribute `value` should be a string. If you intend to do this, you should have to use [Struts2 Type Conversion](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html).

The easiest way to solve your problem is to put your list into session. here is the link [SessionAware](http://www.splinter.com.au/how-to-use-sessions-with-struts-2/).

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk, finally which approach you tried.  if you used  Struts2 Type Conversion, could you please share the piece of code... I already using a session that has some issues with multitab.

Comment: can you please explain how this can be done using  Struts2 Type conversion ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to an java variable to html field for purpose of caching/storing. Since you are using Struts, you could have store this ArrayList variable as part of your form bean.

Comment: @satheesh...well satish,I have to access this list in future,therefore.